# How to avoid Cache restore time outs

Tags: caching, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I do a cache of the maven repository using `Cache@2` to prevent additional downloads especially since Maven Central may yield zero byte files.

However, I am getting events such as this on my build log and when it occurs it significantly slows down the build step.

```
2020-02-14T03:24:14.9261543Z Information, Downloaded 340.2 MB out of 447.6 MB (76%).
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3130567Z Warning, [https://37bvsblobprodcus311.blob.core.windows.net/db184fb09aee8f4ae39869ebeab81ab1ad/7FE2B04FAB9DCB08C78F137CCA2FDA2D5E37B05B5DBCA1D7EDD23F7DB5D580B301?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=mZZ1kK00Gc2cg5m6dyRB3XUYVB40dxJkvBMbXW4D3cM%3D&spr=https&se=2020-02-15T03%3A29%3A57Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-c561122c-76784a8c-be2cb59f-c79091dc-session-eacd1913-b0014305-a33f0081-46cabc28] Try 1/5, non-retryable exception caught. Throwing. Details:
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3131821Z Task was requested to be canceled. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3132112Z    at System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3132355Z    at System.Net.Http.NoWriteNoSeekStreamContent.<>c.<SerializeToStreamAsync>b__4_0(Task t, Object s)
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3132630Z    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3133177Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3133445Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3133903Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3134179Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore(Task serializeToStreamTask, MemoryStream tempBuffer)
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3134413Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3134691Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TaskCancellationExtensions.EnforceCancellation[TResult](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 makeMessage, String file, String member, Int32 line)
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3134970Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass57_0.<<GetRedirectResponseAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3135439Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3135708Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3150625Z Warning, [https://37bvsblobprodcus311.blob.core.windows.net/db184fb09aee8f4ae39869ebeab81ab1ad/7FE2B04FAB9DCB08C78F137CCA2FDA2D5E37B05B5DBCA1D7EDD23F7DB5D580B301?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=mZZ1kK00Gc2cg5m6dyRB3XUYVB40dxJkvBMbXW4D3cM%3D&spr=https&se=2020-02-15T03%3A29%3A57Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-c561122c-76784a8c-be2cb59f-c79091dc-session-eacd1913-b0014305-a33f0081-46cabc28] Try 1/5, retryable exception caught. Retrying in 00:00:01. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3151412Z    at System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3151697Z    at System.Net.Http.NoWriteNoSeekStreamContent.<>c.<SerializeToStreamAsync>b__4_0(Task t, Object s)
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3151962Z    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3152497Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3152771Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3153248Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3153496Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore(Task serializeToStreamTask, MemoryStream tempBuffer)
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3153749Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3154100Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TaskCancellationExtensions.EnforceCancellation[TResult](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 makeMessage, String file, String member, Int32 line)
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3154606Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass57_0.<<GetRedirectResponseAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3155603Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3155739Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3155929Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass60_0.<<HandleRedirectAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3159451Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2020-02-14T03:24:18.3159789Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-02-14T03:24:19.9319176Z Information, Downloaded 340.2 MB out of 447.6 MB (76%).
2020-02-14T03:24:24.9323050Z Information, Downloaded 352.6 MB out of 447.6 MB (79%).
```

Is there any way of avoiding that?  I have also checked https://status.dev.azure.com/ and there is no indication of any issues with it.  These are with the **paid** Azure Devops agent pool not a private agent pool.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar issue that has been open [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11864). You can join in the discussion of this thread or open new issue for above case.

you can try the workaround of using `continueOnError: true` on the cache task to prevent it from failing the build.

```
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json'
    restoreKeys: |
       npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
       npm
    path: $(npm_config_cache)
  displayName: Cache npm

  continueOnError: true
```

Comment: it doesn't actually fail the build.  It just slows down.

Comment: You can vote up on the open issue mentioned above, or create a new one to report this issue. Hope the development team will look into this and provide a fix soon.